# Groupby and frequency count does not return the right value

Tags: python, pandas

I am using this code to group companies and to a frequency count. However, the returned result did not group the companies

```
freq = df.groupby(['company'])['recruitment'].size()


I got some result similar to this. 
             recruitment
company      
  Data Co       3
  Data Co       8
  Apple Co      3
  Apple Co      6
```

I have two questions:

1. why this groupby did not group same companies?
2. When I put freq.columns. It only shows recruitment column, company dissapeared. Is there anyway to show two columns both company and recruitment?

Comment: There is no way to tell without seeing your actual data, but I am guessing there may be slight differences in your company names such as a trailing white space, or a hidden character.

Comment: It is working fine for me... Please include some sample data from your dataframe but the groupby should work. Regarding your second question, maybe what you need is to `reset_index()` your freq df and then `freq.columns`.

Answer (score 0):

If the company name look the 'same' then you have whitespace at front or end, I am adding the upper convert all to upper case as well.

```
freq = df.groupby(df['company'].str.strip().str.upper())['recruitment'].size()
```